# Bitcoin Cash ABC - sendrawtransaction Error | Code : -26

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet, bitcoin-abc

Tried to make a single signature transfer between two address generated using node in regtest mode. During which I got the following 
Error -> `mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation) (code 16)`

Following was the flow.

1. createrawtransaction -> args: `[ UTXO (txid,vout,scriptPubKey,amount), Receiver address, change address]`
   -> **Success**
2. signrawtransactionwithkey -> `args: [Hex-Transaction (output of createrawtransaction), PrivateKey, UTXO (txid,vout,scriptPubKey,amount) ]` -> **Success**
3. sendrawtransaction -> `args: [Hex- Signed Transaction (output of signrawtransactionwithkey)]` -> **Failed**

From basic research, many suggested to add amount field in the signrawtransactionwithkey, Which I did, even after then I was getting the same error.

It is to be noted that the this error came all of a sudden, the Node setup was working fine for months. This happens only in a particular linux machine. Is there any other factors in the host machine can be affect Bitcoin Cash ABC node and cause this issue?

Bitcoin Cash ABC Node running in Regtest mode.

Answer (score -1):

This error may arise due to older having older versions too, try updating the core. I got this error in 0.20.8 but later I updated the node to 0.21.8 it works fine. Not sure what is happening, or is there any kind of expiry to the Bitcoin Core ABC releases.